# Can we have smb mount point with spaces in OS X?

Tags: macos, bash

I am using following piece of code in my script which maps a shared folder in windows to OS X.

```
smb_entry="${mount_point} -fstype=smbfs,soft ://${username}:${password}@${host}/${share_name}"

echo "${smb_entry}" >> /etc/auto_smb

automount -vc
```

This piece of code works good if there is no spaces for the share folder `${share_name}` as well as local mount point `${mount_point}`. For share folder with spaces the solution is to replace the spaces with its hexadecimal value but similar is not the case with the local mount point with spaces in it. Typical examples are

`/Users/govind/Desktop/mount point -fstype=smbfs,soft ://username:password@192.168.54.26/testShare` does not work

`/Users/govind/Desktop/mount_point -fstype=smbfs,soft ://username:password@192.168.54.26/jumpCloudShare` works

So is it possible to have spaces in the mount point path??

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Ask on https://apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: You need to quote it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to show the OS that `mount point` is *one word* (one *single* argument). Do do that, you have several options:

- "quote it"
- escape\ all\ spaces

Otherwise *each space separated word* will be treated as an argument.

Comment: That is correct we have to show the path as one single word.. but commenting is not helping. I have commented the spaces in the entries like this `/Users/ABC/Desktop/mount\ point -fstype=smbfs,soft ://username:password@192.168.xx.xx/testShare` which is mounting with the name `mount\`` on the desktop and files present in the share folder are not visible too.

Comment: @GovindKarmakar, then try to drag this folder right to the terminal and copy the path. It will be escaped automatically so it's recognized correctly.

Comment: The path remained same as it was with the space escaped.

Answer (score 0):

From the [`auto_master(5)` man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/auto_master.5.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/5/auto_master):

> Special characters, such as white space characters, a dollar sign, or an ampersand can be quoted by escaping them with a backslash (\); this prevents white space from being interpreted as a field separator [...]

```
mount_point="${mount_point/ /\\ }"
```

Comment: Commenting the path does not seems to work as I have given this entry in `/etc/auto_smb` file                                          `/Users/ABC/Desktop/mount\ point -fstype=smbfs,soft ://username:password@192.168.xx.xx/testShare` here the space is escaped but the drive is getting mounted with the name `mount\\` and the actual contents of the drive are not visible.

Answer (score 0):

The current answer is no, you cannot have any spaces. Automount has an obvious bug whereby it treats `\` and/or `"` as regular characters. So you *cannot* escape spaces.